# C++ static library and platform toolset compatibility

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I recently created a static C++ library in Visual Studio 2008. 
In this project i used some methods of the `std::string` class.
Now i want to use this library in a Visual Studio 2013 project.

The problem is:
Both Visual Studio versions use different platform toolsets and the project will not compile because of linker errors like:

> Error 4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator >::basic_string,class std::allocator >(void)"
>   (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ)

Is there any way to make a library compatible with all platform toolsets and using some standard classes like `std::string`?

FYI: VS2008 is using v90 platform toolset and VS2013 is using v120 platform toolset.

Thanks.

**Edit:**
If i use some standard methods in the library like `std::vector`, i can't implement the library anymore.

This works:

```
unsigned int TestClass::TestMethod()
{   
    return 2;
}
```

This doesn't:

```
unsigned int TestClass::TestMethod()
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> vtest;
    vtest.push_back(0xff);

    return 2;
}
```

Error:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void
>   __cdecl std::_String_base::_Xran(void)" (?_Xran@_String_base@std@@SAXXZ) referenced in function "public: class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > & __thiscall std::basic_string,class std::allocator >::assign(class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)"
>   (?assign@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEAAV12@ABV12@II@Z)

RT lib is set to /MT and whloe program optimization is disabled (/GL).

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you take a look at the runtime library? There might be a mismatch (/MD /MT options)

Comment: If i change the Runtime Library options to /MTd it works well but only in the debug mode. 
If i change it to /MT to compile a release i get following error: Error 1 error C1047: The object or library file 'C:\Users\...\TestLib\TestLib.lib' was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries

Comment: Any chance to have those lib rebuilt with the new compiler?

Comment: Of course. But is this new generated library compatible with older compilers?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it: you have an old library and you want to use it in a VS2013 project, right? Can't you recompile that library with VS2013 along with your project and have everything up-to-date?

Comment: The problem is: This library will be used by different Visual Studio versions.

Comment: Try to disable /GL and see if that goes away

Comment: HA! Working! Thanks a lot Marco!

Comment: Great, I'll make it an answer in case it could be useful for someone else

Comment: Bear in mind that there was a change in what was exported out of the C++ runtime sometime between 2008 and 2013 (e.g. std::string is no longer exported). As you see, it can affect more than just the std::string exports. In general, you don't want to mix C++ runtimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

I created a dll instead of a static library.

Also make sure that program optimization (/GL) is disabled and check the /MT /MD options.

To create a dll i set the configuration type of the library to "Dynamic Linked Library (.dll)" and defined `__declspec(dllexport)` in the header files like:

```
#define TEST_EXPORT
#ifdef TEST_EXPORT
#define TEST __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define TEST __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif


class TestClass
{
public:
    std::string TEST TestMethod(); 
};
```

Comment: This way you have a `std::string` on the DLL interface and it will/may break at runtime also. (See my edit)

Comment: I wrote a test environment for my library and it works pretty well at the moment. It passed all my tests.

I compiled the lib on platform toolset v90, and used it on platform toolset v90 and v120.

Comment: even though i'll change my library due to your edit to make sure it works for every toolset. thanks!

Comment: It may well work. I guess that MS didn't change the std::string implementation too much since 2008, then again, they may well fiddle around with the buffer size for the small-string-optimization.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in the comments, you need to make sure that:

- There's no runtime library mismatch (`/MT /MD` options) with the older library
- `/GL` (i.e. whole program optimization) is disabled

Comment: Edit: this is part of OP solution since he edited the post and added issues afterwards

Answer (score 1):

While [Marco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26178312/321013) is certainly useful on a technical level, you have a deeper problem with this design:

*You cannot use any `std` library types in the (public) headers of your static library.* Not. Any.

While it *may* work for some it may break for others, and you will find zero documentation or help which ones will work.

`std::` types are *not* (guaranteed to be) binary compatible between different platform toolset versions, so using any in any interface or as a class member will break sooner or later.

By example:

1. This is OK, use of vector is purely internal:

   ```
   unsigned int TestClass::TestMethod()
   {
       std::vector<unsigned char> vtest;
       vtest.push_back(0xff);

       return 2;
   }
   ```
2. This will break, *at runtime*, if the two platform toolset compilers+options produce a different binary layout for vector objects:

   ```
   unsigned int TestClass::Test2(std::vector<unsigned char> const& vparam)
   {
       vparam.push_back(0xff);

       return 2;
   }
   ```
3. This will also break for different binary layout:

   ```
   class TestClass {
     std::vector<int> m_buffer;
     ...
   };
   ```

And the problem with a static library, as opposed to a DLL, is of course that it is a lot less obvious what goes into the interface and what not (because there's no need to `dllexport` or anything.)

Do note however, that the technical problem per se is absolutely the same for the DLL as for the static LIB. I.e., you can not use any `std` types in the interface of your DLL/LIB, that includes, at least:

- class members (even private ones)
- function parameters (*regardless* of whether you pass by-value, by-ref or by-pointer)
- function return values